# HttpClientErrorException: 404 null

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I try to call the address in the controller using RestTemplate and as a result I want to get OK or NOT FOUND status
I do so in this controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/thanks")
public ModelAndView confirmAccount(
        @RequestParam String token,
        UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder
) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders());

    UriComponents uriComponents
            = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/register/token/{token}").buildAndExpand(token);

    ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate
            .exchange(uriComponents.toUri(),
                      HttpMethod.PUT,
                      entity,
                      Boolean.class);

    return response.getStatusCode().toString().equals("200")
            ?  new ModelAndView("redirect:/signIn") : new ModelAndView("tokenNotFound");
}
```

I call this address of the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register/token/{token}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public
HttpEntity<Boolean> confirmAccount(
        @PathVariable String token
) {
    Optional<User> userOptional = userService.findByActivationToken(token);

    if(userOptional.isPresent()) {
        User user = userOptional.get();

        user.setActivationToken(null);
        user.setEnabled(true);

        userService.saveUser(user);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
}
```

As a result, she throws me out in the console

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:549) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at com.service.app.controller.RegisterController.confirmAccount(RegisterController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
```

Why does RestTemplate not want to return the status 404 as a result?
    enter code here

Comment: What url are you calling to test the flow?

Comment: Sorry. I map the entire controller to' /register'. Here I corrected the address.

Comment: When is HttpClientErrorException exception occurring, while calling "/thanks" or "/register/token"? More stacktrace can be useful

Comment: First you need to check if you are calling /register/token/{token} it correctly? If it is actually going inside confirmAccount Method, that you can check by putting a breakpoint of a log statement. If it is not hitting this method then problem is in calling the method which will also throw 404 but it will be thrown by Spring.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled a lot with this exception Even URL is absolutely correct and relative URLs works for POST request. **404 means URL specify in RestTemplate or HttpRequest for GET type method is incorrect due to Query Param or Request Params or Path Params.** Reason Query/Path param's value contain special character that converted or interpreted differently. **Let Say queryParams is email=test@xyz.com which converted into email=test20%xyz41%.com**

Solution: Decoding while passing query/path params.

Add Following code at server side [controller code]

ServerSide[Controller]:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
 import java.net.URLEncoder;

String encodedEmail = URLDecoder.decode(email, "UTF-8");
```

It perfectly working and tested code.

Comment: This one woked for me

Answer (score 0):

a simple explanation can be HttpClientErrorException is unchecked exception. Java docs for this exception tells, 'Exception thrown when an HTTP 4xx is received'
ref - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html

so try handling exception with appropriate try/catch and throws

Comment: Exactly. RestTemplate throws exceptions and you have to catch them https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I left out a forward slash at the end of my endpoint and got the error. After putting it on at the end of my url it worked fine.